# Twitter Style Script

Tags: web-apps, ios, javascript, php, web-services

I have had requests from some managers that our company should have an internal twitter style tool/website to help build engagement and communication in the workplace.

I am looking to find some software that we can use internally and preferably a phone app we can link to it as well.

Is there anything solid on the corporate level that exists like this?

Comment: By Twitter style do you mean a styled Twitter feed or a tool like Twitter?

Comment: Same functionality as twitter, user accounts, feeds, hash tags, all that stuff

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is a customised `Social Network Service` `(SNS)` aimed for employees' cooperation.

There is a similar type of mature tool called `group project management tool`, like:

> [trello](https://trello.com/): *"Organize anything, together"*

However, since you want twitter like, `customised tool service` would be a perfect choice if money is not a problem, like:

> [DigitalCreative](http://digitalcreative.asia/myportfolio/live-the-principles-adidas-china/) *The linked example should demonstrate their ability to build what you need. Also, with customisation, you can even ask it to be like twitter style (by using Bootstrap, an open source web development tool kit from twitter).*